# How do admins manage RTO for sql server with large number of dbs?

Tags: sql-server, recovery

Assuming I have 140 dbs and daily full and log backups.

The crash recovery process would be to restore each db one by one using the backups.

Therefore the RTO to get the system up ready will be high since the number of dbs is large.

How do experienced dbas manage RTO in such situations?

Comment: RTO is defined by your business requirements, not by the number of databases. You then define the recovery process to meet the RTO.

Comment: Have you considered other options than restoring from backup? If your business partner are not satisfied with this approach, offer them other alternatives. DBAs do not decide on RTO. We implement after agreeing and documenting in partnership with the business.

Comment: Any example of alternatives? I'm just learning.

Answer (score 1):

In such a scenario where you need to restore so many databases, you're best off creating scripts or application code to help automate the process.

There are also tools to help database and server management out there such as [dbatools](https://dbatools.io) which are really powerful for automation and scripting.

Additionally, if a quick RTO (Recovery Time Objective) is required, this is where other DR (Disaster Recovery) solutions can be more helpful, such as [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).